# Do I need a trasit visa?

Tags: transit-visas, iranian-citizens

I'm traveling from UK to Iran, and then return from Iran to UK and have a stop in Amsterdam. As I have the UK visa, do I still need the transit visa in Amsterdam?

All the best,
Elahe

Comment: I see no *transit* in your question. How are you travelling, any stops in between? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Are you asking whether a UK visitor visa can be used for multiple entries into the UK?